# Are Nikon lenses with electronic aperture compatible with extension tubes with electronic contacts?

Tags: nikon, aperture, extension-tubes

Can extension tubes with electrical contacts be used with Nikon's electronically-controlled aperture lenses, such as the Nikkor 16–80mm f/2.8–4E ED VR, when combined with a compatible camera body, such as the D500?

Answer (score 1):

If the extension tubes have a full set of electrical contacts that match the most recent Nikon cameras and lenses, all lens-body communications should pass through.

Check the tubes to be sure they have a set of ten electrical contacts.  If the tubes have only about five electrical contacts, they're fully compatible with  only AF and AF-D lenses.  AF-I and AF-S lenses, introduced in the early 1990s, use anywhere from 7-10 contacts, depending on whether they are VR lenses and use electronic or mechanical aperture control.